# Direct I/O on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, io

I'm trying to enable Direct I/O on /opt (/dev/sda6, ext4) on Linux Mint 13. What I'm trying is:

```
mount -o dio,rw /dev/sda6 /opt
```

as root.

The system responds with:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/hda2
```

`dmesg` is reporting:

```
EXT4-fs (sda6): Unrecognized mount option "dio" or missing value.
```

I can't figure out which parameter to set to enable direct I/O (and even if mounting with direct I/O is possible for ext4). Besides this, if ext4 should not support direct I/O, could someone please  indicate a filesystem to use on Linux which does?

Comment: In Linux, direct I/O is generally requested by the application, not via mount options.

Comment: Why do you want all disk accesses direct in the first place?

Comment: @MIfe I need it due to the fact that I'm in an embedded environment and my unit is powered by solar panels, so it may suddenly lose power due to the lack of enough solar radiation. If the writings to my database are not completed, it could be end up corrupted. Unfortunately I'm not in the position of having a UPS or similar to handle power failure gracefully.

Comment: If it's an embedded system, why aren't you using a filesystem designed for embedded systems?

Comment: @MichaelHampton : could you suggest one? the ext4 filesystem has been chosen by previous implementors.

Comment: Consider making your database something that is ACID compliant and claims consistency even during power failure. Like SQLite.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @MIfe; unfortunately I'm stuck with MySQL (myIsam) right now and switching to SQLite is hardly an option at this late stage.

Comment: This would have been really helpful if someone actually answered the question.

Comment: I came here from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476658/deactivating-disk-cache-for-specific-device-or-partition-play-2160p-video-off?noredirect=1#comment871384_476658

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ext4 doesn't have a `dio` mount option (I believe AIX and Solaris do) but it does have `dioread_lock` and `dioread_nolock` mount options. From the `mount(8)` manual page:

> **dioread_lock/dioread_nolock**
>
> Controls whether or not ext4 should use
>   the DIO read locking. If the dioread_nolock option is specified  ext4 
>   will allocate uninitialized extent before buffer write and convert the
>   extent to initialized after IO completes.
>
> This approach allows ext4 code to avoid using inode mutex, which
>   improves scalability on high  speed  storages.  However this does not
>   work with data journaling and dioread_nolock option will be ignored
>   with kernel warning.  Note that dioread_nolock code path is only used
>   for extent-based files.  Because of the restrictions this  options 
>   comprises it is off by default (e.g. dioread_lock).

That said, as others have mentioned, direct I/O is normally enabled by setting the `O_DIRECT` flag in the `open(2)` system call - ie, it's controlled by the application, not a mount option. `O_DIRECT` is supported by ext4, **unless** you're using the `data=journal` mount option (see [ext4 documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt) and [this commit](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=84ebd795613488992b273220c2937d575d27d2a9)).

For InnoDB I know the `innodb_flush_method` parameter can be used to enable `O_DIRECT`, but I'm not aware of a similar setting for MyISAM?